# Async / await with task.run vs task.run and continuewith in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have installed async package in .net 4.0. this gives me the ability to use async / await keywords in my applications.

as i have understood until now i can use wrap my task.run code in async / await and have the same result as using task.run with continuewith.

Is this true? or there are deeper differences?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing with `ContinueWith`. But yes, often you can use `await` to achieve the same effects you'd previously have achieved using `ContinueWith`. What you *can't* do is things like "continue with this code only on failure" - you just use normal exception handling for that. As AlexH says, there will be further differences in terms of the overall behaviour of your `async` method - but in most cases I'd say that's *desirable*. Basically, the asynchrony of the code flows, so async methods tend to call more async methods, etc.

I suggest you read up on what `async`/`await` is about (there are loads of resources out there - I'd recommend the ["Consuming the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173.aspx) page on MSDN as one starting point.

Answer (score 4):

There will be a difference if you introduce async keyword in your functions prototypes; the exceptions will be thrown at the Task caller's level.
Without the async keyword, you have to check the TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted status to get the exception.